# Forum solution (asp.net c#) handling Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, active-directory, forum

We are searching for a Forum solution to integrate with one of the intranet solutions we have developed.

At the moment we are testing **[Jitbit AspNetForum](http://www.jitbit.com/asp-net-forum.aspx)** which seems to integrate quite well but it seems not to be focused on using it with Active Directory and Windows Authentication. We are not getting enough control over certain bits of system (for example: getting user screen name as DisplayName from Active Directory and not user domain\login).

The other solution we are considering is **yetanotherforum.net** but we had some problems integrating that with our application. Since it is getting quite a lot good press here and on few other websites we will try again from scratch.

Maybe you are using any other .net forum solution you could recommend or you have heard about ones worth investigating? Basically we need customizable forum focused (or with some decent features) for windows authentication and integration with active directory. The package we need has to be based on .Net Framework 2.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give DotNetNuke a try.

It has a forum module and I am pretty sure it supports integration with Active Directory.